# Should I use logs to solve for p?

Tags: linear-algebra

I cant solve p in the following equation:

1.5p+1=2^p

Ive tried using logs , yet without success. I can solve it via substitution p = 2

Comment: It can't be done with logs, I think.  There is probably a solution with Lambert's W function, but I expect they wanted you to try possible solutions until you find them, as you did.  I think you have missed a solution.

Comment: Sorry ! I was typing what Michael asked you to find !

Comment: Is your equation $1.5p+1=2^p$ or something different ?

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle5p=2^p-1$ is odd for $p>0$

$\implies p$ must be odd $=2q+1$(say)

$\implies2^{2q+1}=5(2q+1)+1\equiv6\pmod{10}$

But, $2^{4a+1}\equiv2,2^{4a+3}\equiv8\pmod{10}$

Comment: Isn't that 1.5p+1, rather than 5p+1?

Comment: @Michael, I think, that is the Serial no. of the problem. Do you have any other interpretation ?

Comment: In this case, $p=2$ is not a solution.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, I've derived that there can be no solution in positive integers